# How do I change my default shell to bash if I don't have access to chsh nor /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm working on a university remote Linux account, and the default shell is sadly `csh` without tab completion. How can I change my account's default shell to `bash`? `chsh` is not available.

Comment: What system does the university use to store accounts? `ldapmodify` might work.

Comment: Or, if they are using NIS, `ypchsh` should be the proper command.

Comment: If you just want tab completion you could add these to your ~/.cshrc
 `set filec` and `set autolist`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should probably try asking your sysadmins if they can change your default shell for you. If they can't or won't (as was the case when I was in college), the workaround I used was to add

```
# Exec bash if using an interactive shell.
if ($?prompt) then
    setenv SHELL /path/to/bash
    exec $SHELL
endif
```

to `.cshrc`. (Make sure to replace `/path/to/bash` with a real path, of course. This could even be a version of `bash` that resides under your home directory, if the system-provided version is too out-of-date for your taste.) For efficiency, it's best to do this as early in the `.cshrc` as feasible, so that you avoid additional `.cshrc` processing that will become moot once `bash` replaces the `csh` process.

Comment: This did not work for me at my university. I will probably have to talk to the sysadmin.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply connect with

```
ssh -t yourhost bash
```

to execute the Bash shell automatically when you log in.

---

From the comments below you can see the alternative

```
ssh -t yourhost exec bash
```

`exec` will run a new process and exit the old one, so the `csh` process will exit directly.

If append `-l` at the end of the command as an argument to Bash, it will be treated as a login shell, but perhaps that is not needed.

Comment: `ssh -t yourhost exec -a bash -l bash` to replace the original shell completely, rather than running as a process inside the initial shell.

Comment: @chepner: Interesting, I'm using a simple `ssh -t host bash` solution myself in a similar situation, but your way is better. I haven't thought of `exec` at all, thanks! I'll update the post with your suggestion.

Comment: I got a little fancy, though, using arguments for the `bash` built-in command `exec`.

Comment: @chepner: Ah yes, I tried it now on a host with zsh as default shell and it fails on both `-a` and `-l`. I'll modify the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found was one over on stackexchange. Here is the link [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46645/how-can-i-use-bash-as-my-login-shell-when-my-sysadmin-refuses-to-let-me-change-i) and here is the solution:

create a .profile file in your home dir and paste in the following, or add to the end of your .profile if you already have one.

```
case $- in
  *i*)
    # Interactive session. Try switching to bash.
    if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then # do nothing if running under bash already
      bash=$(command -v bash)
      if [ -x "$bash" ]; then
        export SHELL="$bash"
        exec "$bash"
      fi
    fi
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

i searched a lot when your using LADP authentication via PAM , i think the best solution is to put 
SHELL=/bin/bash exec /bin/bash
in .profile file in your user home directory